# Rename SQLServer instance after rename computer

Tags: sql-server, sql-management-studio

I have SQL Server 2012 running on Windows Server 2012. I renamed the Windows Server and need to adjust the SQL Server for the new name to get my Maintenance Plans running.

When I run `Select @@ServerName` I get the old server name.

If I try to run the sp_drop/addserver

```
exec sp_dropserver "oldservername\instancename"
Go
exec sp_addserver "newservername\instancename", local
Go
```

I get the following error:

Msg 15015, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_dropserver, Line 45
The server 'oldservername\instancename' does not exist. Use sp_helpserver to show available servers.
Msg 15028, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_addserver, Line 79
The server 'newservername\instancename' already exists.

`sp_helpserver` shows the new server name though

How can I correct this so my SQL Server Agent can run maintenance plans again?

Comment: Have you restarted SQL after you ran the sp_dropserver and sp_addserver commands?

Comment: That was part of the answer. I thought I had restarted after but I guess my last restart was before.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the server after running the drop/add server commands got the @@ServerName correct. I had to change the owner of the jobs to a different user because they were mapped to oldservername\username.